# cassandra version compatibility with 3.7?

Tags: cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

Is the spring-data-cassandra version 1.4.2 compatible with cassandra version 3.7? I get the following error when I try to connect:

```
Error creating bean with name 'cassandraSession': Invocation of init method failed;
nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
io/netty/util/concurrent/EventExecutor
```

Answer (score 3):

No, *Spring Data Cassandra* 1.4.x is [based on](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra/blob/1.4.x/pom.xml#L36-L37) the **2.x** DataStax's *Cassandra* driver.

However, in *Spring Data Cassandra* 1.5 (Ingalls) release series (currently at 1.5 M1), we have [upgraded](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra/blob/1.5.0.M1/pom.xml#L73) the DataStax *Cassandra* driver to **3.0.3**.  We have also removed support for the DataStax DSE (DataStax Enterprise) driver since it is unnecessary for SD *Cassandra* functionality.

There were significant changes in the 3.0 version of DataStax's Java driver API requiring us to introduce 3.0 support in 1.5.  We would not be able to back port these changes without adversely affecting 1.4 users.

You can find out more by reading our SD [Ingalls M1 release announcement](https://spring.io/blog/2016/07/27/spring-data-release-train-ingalls-m1-released).

Also, you can follow the development of SD *Cassandra* 1.5 on the [Wiki](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/wiki/Release-Train-Ingalls).

Feedback is always welcomed, either with [PRs](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra/pulls) or through [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS).

Comment: Thank you. I was able to use the snapshot of 1.5.0 for my application and it works. Do you know when 1.5.0 will be released? http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-cassandra/

Comment: 1.5 M1 was released end of July (July 27th).  RC1 will be about 4-6 weeks out from that date and then GA follows in another ~4-6 weeks.  The release cycles are a bit more complicated now that Spring Boot builds on the SD Release Trains, so we try to coordinate with the Spring Boot team as well.  My guess is 1.5 GA should be on or a bit before November 1.